# How can I modify files at server by servlet?

Tags: java, file, servlets

I need to modify html file that is placed at server folder from my servlet.
No other way than read it by `FileInputStream` to `byte[]`, convert to `String[]` splitting lines by `"\n"`, change what I need and then rewrite it.
I don't see.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking to do.  Are you trying to edit a file that was uploaded by a servlet? Or are you trying to modify a file that was deployed as part of your application (WAR/EAR/JAR)? What have you tried? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by design. Your server might just have to serve a .WAR file. If the server is not configured to unzip it, your server will have to read all files directly from this archive. You can now guess that you cannot write at this location.

You would need to create some kind of working directory and also serve files from there, too. You can always use this directory as working directory:

```
File workingDir = (File)servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
```

Comment: There is directory "files" with .html It's available to "myserver.org/files/file.html"
Can I edit files in it?

Comment: I don't know that. I was just telling you that you cannot edit files which are supplied within the .WAR file.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway. It was silly idea, I implemented my plan via JSF.